# Cordova: having error in initial hello project with Xcode

Tags: xcode, cordova-3

I am facing this error while running my initial Hello project from 
[cordova tutorial link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html#iOS%20Platform%20Guide)

i am getting this error:

cordova-hello Mylap14$ cordova platform add ios
[Error: Xcode is (probably) not installed, specifically the command `xcodebuild` is unavailable or erroring out. Output of `xcodebuild -version` is: xcodebuild: error: developer tools not installed; download from http://developer.apple.com]

i have cordova 3.0.0 and Xcode 4.5.2 on Mac 10.7.5
Where does cordova search for xcode path. Where does it expect Xcode. Can i give relative path?

Answer (score 0):

You may need Mac 10.8 - I forget why but I had to install 10.8 in order to get iOS development set up.